# Read from "start" to "stop" as hex values from raw file using FileStream

Tags: c#

I want to read from a "start" to a "stop" from a raw image file that I've created with FKT Imager.

I have a code that works, but I dont know if it's the best way of doing it?

```
// Read file, byte at the time (example 00, 5A)
int start = 512;
int stop = 3345332;

FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.001", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
int hexIn;
String hex;
String data = "";

fs.Position = start;
 for (int i = 0; i < stop; i++) { // i = offset in bytes
     hexIn = fs.ReadByte();

     hex = string.Format("{0:X2}", hexIn);
     data = data + hex;
 } //for
 fs.Close();

Console.Writeline("data=" + data);
```

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` instead of a string for `data`, to avoid a lot of memory allocations for temporary strings.

Comment: " but I dont know if it's the best way of doing it?" it depends always on your aim. Is your aim to get a huge string of hex values?

Comment: *"code ... works, ... best way of doing it"* = [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to read a range of bytes from within a file. Why not reading all bytes in one go into an array and then do the transformation?

```
    private string ReadFile(string filename, int offset, int length)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[length];

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            fs.Position = offset;
            fs.Read(data, 0, length);
        }

        return string.Join("", data.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));
    }
```